# why buffer parameter in new object of stream reader declaration ؟

Tags: c#

i have this code

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path,Encoding.Default,true,1))
        {
            char[] c = null;
            c = new char[15];
            sr.Read(c, 0, c.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("first 15 characters:");
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            // writes - "abcdefghijklmno"
            sr.BaseStream.Seek(2, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            sr.DiscardBufferedData();

            Console.WriteLine("Back to offset 2 and read to end: ");
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
            // writes - "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            // without DiscardBufferedData, writes - "pqrstuvwxyzcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

        }
```

i am learning system.io from MSDN Documention .

but i cant understand why there are parameter named ' minimum buffer size ' , i tried to change this value but when i change there are no any thing happen to output in any case of change i do

Notice : i'm confused about meaning of ' buffer ' can any one explain it to me
because i tried to search about it but i cant understand any thing

Thanks :)

Comment: [Possible duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148131/streamreader-and-buffer-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Output will be the same, it's the question of efficiency. Reading from file is expensive; however, usually reading 1000 characters at once is much faster than reading 1 character 1000 times (since there is a big constant overhead). Therefore, it's beneficial to read multiple characters in advance, and save them somewhere. This "somewhere" is called a buffer.

Comment: @dyukha ok do you mean that Buffer is like a container for data ?

Comment: Depending on what exactly you mean, yes.